# Network Credentials not saving in CredentialCache

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, networkcredentials

I have to assign the username and password from credential cache to Httpwebrequest.When i assign to cache it is working but when assigning to Webrequest from cache it shows null. Where i'm wrong?

```
string strServer = "";
        strServer = "http://servername/";
        Uri uri = new Uri(strServer);
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        CredentialCache cache = new CredentialCache();  
        cache.Add(new Uri(strServer), "Basic", new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password","Domain"));
        cache.Add(new Uri(strServer), "Digest", new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password","Domain"));
        request.Credentials = cache;
```

Comment: Santhosh, are you getting an exception when trying to get the response of the request? If so, can you please paste that in, as well?

Comment: No i didnt get any exception.

Comment: @BrianWarshaw: Is there any solution??

Comment: Well, let's work through this. If you didn't get an exception, how did you know that it's null?

Comment: @BrianWarshaw: During debugging i noticed tat.

Comment: Right, but if you're not getting an exception, how are you noticing it during debugging? Do you have a breakpoint, or is something else happening?

Comment: @BrianWarshaw: Got breakpoint over the last line and checked it.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure what to say without some more information. Everything looks ok, though you can clean it up a little by not creating new `Uri` instances in the `cache.Add` lines (just use the `uri` variable you've created earlier). That shouldn't have any effect in terms of nullness, though.

What are you checking at your breakpoint specifically that is null? The `Username` and `Password` properties of the `NetworkCredential`?

Answer (score 0):

Hello,
You just need to retrieve the credential from the cache, and then add it to the web request,  example bellow:

```
    cache.Add(new Uri(strServer), "Basic", new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password","Domain"));
    cache.Add(new Uri(strServer), "Digest", new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password","Domain"));    

    NetworkCredential  currentCredentials= cache.GetCredential(new Uri(strServer), "Basic");  //Get specific credential
    request.Credentials = currentCredentials; //Allocate credential
```